# What's a good programming language for a Windows GUI application that's not Java?

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages

I've been developing an application in Java for a few months now. The more I work on it, the more I realize what a bad programming languege Java really is, and the longer I wait, the harder it'll be to switch. So I'm switching now. I'd need a language that can handle GUI and MySQL queries. And most importantly, that I'll LOVE. Because it's come to the point where I literally hate Java now.

And if it matters I'd prefer to program in Linux, but It's not necessary. And it'll be an application for Windows.

Comment: Delphi. I am pretty sure this question is a duplicate, though.

Comment: Isn't Delphi dying ? My vote goes to C# and .NET.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand oh please not Delphi

Comment: C++ with a cross-platform library?

Comment: @hauntsaninja how C++ is better then C# except for existence of mature cross-platform libs (for which author didn't asked)?

Comment: @driis: No, that is simply plain wrong (very wrong).

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, Of course it's subjective, and Delphi is still in use, I know - but if you take community size as an indicator, it's interesting to see that there about `0.05 %` Delphi tagged questions on SO compared to C#. For someone needing to learn a new language, the ability to get answers to questions fast, might be a deciding factor.

Comment: This is a weak question.  You say you don't like java, and want a replacement.  But you don't mention the most important factor - why don't you like java?

Comment: @driis: That last argument isn't valid. At SO, Delphi questions get answered very rapidly.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Delphi questions probably only get answered very rapidly because it has a much smaller community compared to C# these days and since it is a much smaller community, you can probably bet that they're all on here trying to get answers and since there aren't as many Delphi questions, _that's_ why they get answered so quickly - because there's not as much to go through.

Comment: Being bad a Java does not make Java a bad language. Thousands upon thousands of programmers use Java and love it.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend C# and .net. They make one of the most mature and one of the most productive environment for developing under Windows. Plus for you C# is similar to Java (in it's best parts, you will not hate it)

Comment: +1. Migrating from Java to C# will seem easy, especially if you have studied a C-like language before.

Comment: @this is a dead end tell me why didn't you like java

Comment: @Andrey many many reasons that I don't think would fit in this message but the top 2 are (1) it takes too much coding to do very little and (2) too many GUI glitches.

Comment: @this is a dead end: Then you would really like Delphi.

Comment: @this is a dead end: "(1) it takes too much coding to do very little and (2) too many GUI glitches." sounds to me like you just don't know Java well enough. Beware that while C# has more features compared to Java, the specs of the language is also much larger --> more to learn to understand programs if you have little experience. Maybe you should post some of the "too much code" things on stackoverflow and ask the community for simple solutions in Java. Perhaps you will be surprised.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand I coded on delphi for several years then switched to C# and think this is best programming related decision in my professional life.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi is a very good choice. It is really easy to create a new native Windows GUI application, and the language is easy yet powerful. The latest versions have very good support for modern versions of Windows, and Unicode strings are default.

Despite it being a very easy-to-use language, and despite the fact that there are ready-to-use components for most imaginable tasks (including a vast collection of 3rd-party code), it lets the user do things low-level, should she prefer that. For instance, you can manipulate the heap manually, and you can even write ASM code. The Delphi community is very large, and the product is very much alive.

There has been a huge amount of development the last years, and Delphi XE, the latest version, has a lot of new features compared to Delphi 2007 (in between there are Delphi 2009 and Delphi 2010). Hence, Delphi is very much alive. In the near future (I think), a 64-bit compiler is coming. It is a plain misunderstanding that Delphi should be "dying".

Comment: The enormous price hikes however prohibit me from suggesting it, unless one really wants to start as a  self employed db app maker.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: Well, to be honest, the huge amount of obvious quality issues in 10.3 Rio makes it hard for me to recommend Delphi any more. I mean, you cannot even maximize the IDE window without seeing an obvious bug...

Comment: I stopped upgrading at Seattle, when they forced autosubscription, which was pointless to me since I didn't do mobile. I usually upgraded once every few years on the back of a major project.

Answer (score 3):

All very good suggestions and since the user didn't like Java then I won't suggest C#. I'll suggest picking up Ruby instead.

The great thing about developing with Ruby is that you don't have to invest much money to get started.  I hope you try it out.  If not then maybe F# would be a good language to try out.

Added a Link for you: http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/11/getting-started-with-wxruby-gui-toolkit.html

Comment: I was thinking of trying Ruby anyway to develop some web applications. I heard it's very easy with Ruby.

Comment: Yeah...  It's great for the web.  I have been learning it from http://tekpub.com.  They have a lot of video tutorials on the subject.  Oh and so does http://peepcode.com/.

Answer (score 2):

What's the matter with Java? The question will be easier to answer if I'd know what you don't like about it so that I can recommend a language that doesn't have the same things that bother you.

Anyway. I'd rule out .NET since you will probably find there are too many similarities to Java.

I can recommend ObjectPascal, which is a really nice language that I like a lot (although I switched to Java). You can either use the Delphi IDE which is commercial and only available for Windows if I remember correctly or an OpenSource IDE such as [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) which also available for Linux so that you can develop on Linux. Biggest drawback I know: Manual memory management (although there might exist a solution for that that I don't know about).

Another Option would be to do C(++) with a descent library, probably GTK, QT or wxWidgets.

Yet another Option would be D, which has many real great concepts. Unfortunately D is very new and thus there are not many libraries available for D. But for developing GUI components you can use wxD, which is wxWidgets for D. D has built in automatic memory management, which, for me, is a huge plus. Additionally even though D is very similar to C(++) it made many many of the things in C(++) outdated that certainly made sense 30 years ago, but not now (my opinion). A downside is the name though. Try to google for "D" and you know what I mean. Who names a language that way nowadays?? That makes finding solutions for the language with google much harder.

Comment: Hahahaha D. Anyway, my problem with Java is mainly with how glitchy all the GUI components are. I had several bugs while developing this application that other users on Google had too. Most of the time there are solutions, but I prefer it if there wasn't a problem to begin with. For example, on Nimbux, TextArea and the default Checkbox renderer for JTables don't work correctly. I had to mess around with some of the TextArea options to get it to display correctly and I had to create my own CheckBox renderer.

Comment: Also, putting the GUI components on screen takes too much time, and will often not look the way I want it to. The only layout manager that ever worked exactly how I expected was BorderLayout. All the other ones are not intuitive at all. And I hate how on a JPanel, I have to add another JPanel just to get everything in it to center, otherwise it gets stretched out. How annoying. I haven't programmed GUI with any other programming language. The only GUI I've designed without Java was with HTML/CSS/Javascript. A third party layoutmanager I used was PainlessGridbag, that design was much better.

Comment: Ok now the part about coding a lot and getting very little results. In Java, everything has to be in a class. It forces OOP down your throat. At first, when I was learning this in University I thought this was neat, because it kept everything organized. But it gets annoying fast, I don't want every single thing in a class. And there's no option for an anonymous function or class. Or even associative arrays. I have to use a hashmap or create a class for that. Which works, but it forces me to do more than I would have to do in other languages that would allow it.

Comment: In Javascript there's a way to extend a current object. Not inheritance. It's called the object's prototype. When you for example, add a function to that prototype, all objects that use that prototype now have that function. If I want to do this in Java I have to create a new class with this function and then use the object with that class's function.

Comment: It doesn't allow functions to be passed as parameters or returned from functions. It has interfaces, but again, this just takes more time to use.

I really don't understand Java arrays. Whenever I need an array in Java I just use something like ArrayList, because I really don't understand the arrays in Java.

Java forces me to catch exceptions that I don't care about. Hey, how about just not having those exceptions there in the first place?

Comment: Dealing with MySQL in Java is painful. First, the connection keeps dropping every now and then, not just the Connection object, but also PreparedStatements. Checking if they're null or closed doesn't always work I have no idea why. It forces me to catch every single possible SQLException ever even in the ResultSet object. I was thinking of making a general mysql class that would deal with all errors for me and print them on an error label but no. I had to make a separate mysql class for every single GUI class. Why every single GUI class and not one for all? Because it takes too much code.

Comment: @this is a dead end: Sry, but seriously, you sound extremely frustrated with not getting along with some concepts and trying to put it on Java. I know JavaScript quite well and the concept you are refering too is called prototype-based programming and is in contrast to class based programming. MOST OOP-languages use the later. If you are really serious about the things you said, code in JavaScript, Python, PHP or any other high level scripting languages. Python has probably best support for what you want.

Comment: It's not just the concepts. Like I said, some stuff in Java just doesn't work all the time, and I really have no idea why. For example, I was using FormattedTextField class. It was working in some parts of my layout and not in some. Finally fixed it by putting setText("") in the constructor. It says nothing about that in the documentation and I have no idea why that fixes it. Also, every now and then if you open or resize a window in Java, it won't show anything on it or won't resize the components. And this isn't just in the program I coded, it happens in every single Java application.

Comment: FormattedTextFields also fire both the insertUpdate() and removeUpdate() functions in document listeners every time user either inserts or deletes from it. I had to create my own customer listener that checks if the user actually did change something in the text field. It's little annoyances like this that slowly wear down a programmer. I can see why that happens, but I'd rather not deal with it and do more programming instead of accommodating for the mistakes of others.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be a bit difficult to understand, I would recommend C++. It is one of the most powerful languages in the world, and has lots of ways to create GUIs. There is the classic way, with windows.h header (hard to understand), but I'd recommend you Qt, because it is a great framework for almost everything, like single console apps, powerful GUIs...
Also, it can compile cross-platform, so you can develop for multiple OSs.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is Python with wxPython for the GUI aspect.  I find its syntax to be much cleaner than Java's, like the way it enforces good coding style (indentation is syntax, after all), and have become enamored with features like list comprehensions.  There are a number of GUI Building Toolkits available for it as well (wxGlade, XRCed) that allow you to create the skeleton of your UI via drag & drop mechanisms.

Answer (score -1):

id recommended visual basic its easy and simple

Comment: That's a little better suggestion than mine but he mentioned linux so I don't know what he's really after.